# How to create .CIF file from DRX data in a paper, for compound not found in crystallographic database

Tags: computational-chemistry, crystal-structure, software, cheminformatics, x-ray-diffraction

I tried to recover a .CIF file with the crystal structure for the compound discussed in [this 2006 paper](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/znb/62/2/article-p215.xml), strontium hydroxide octahydrate - $\ce{Sr(OH)2·8H2O}$ - from Cambridge Crystallographic Data Centre (CCDC), but couldn't find it. The paper itself has tables with information recovered from x-ray diffraction data, as shown below.

[image]
[image]

Is there any free software or open source tool where I can just type the data from these tables to assemble a crystal structure like the ones I'm used to download from the database?

Comment: If you cannot find any software, as the system is tetragonal and you know $a=b \ne c$  and $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=90$ and the fractional positions given the table, you should be able to reproduce the structure quite easily.

Comment: Recently, this question was [asked on materials.SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/407/how-can-i-create-a-cif-file-from-x-ray-diffraction-data-in-a-paper-for-compoun)

Comment: You can fairly easily create your own CIF with [VESTA](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/) using the space group and unit cell parameters from Table 1 and atomic coordinates from Table 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't find this entry in CCDC's CSD, because the scope of this database are small *organic*, or *organometallic* molecules' crystal structures.  (For large organic molecules, analogue studies' data may be found, e.g., on [wwpdb.org](https://www.wwpdb.org/).)  Because your compound is considered as *inorganic**, you'll find it in the ICSD, the *inorganic crystal structure database*.

Note, the paper includes the statement:

> «Further details of the crystal structure investigation may  be  obtained  from  Fachinformationszentrum Karlsruhe, 76344 Eggenstein-Leopoldshafen, Ger-many (fax: +49-7247-808-666; e-mail: crysdata@fiz-karlsruhe.de,   http://www.fiz-informationsdienste.de/en/DB/icsd/depotanforderung.html) on quoting the depository number CSD-417100.»

Because CCDC and ISCD established in 2018 [a search interface in common](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/), and entries' labels in both databases differ from each other, it is easy to find the record [here](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=417100&DatabaseToSearch=Published).  It is not as comfortable as their own GUI and API interfaces ([example ICSD](https://icsd.fiz-karlsruhe.de/index.xhtml;jsessionid=3FA824640364085663B1AD07F53D1B3D)), but it is possible to download the record's `.cif`.

Note that *complementary* to these two databases, there are others like e.g., the [American Mineralogist Crystal Structure Database](http://rruff.geo.arizona.edu/AMS/amcsd.php) and the [COD](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/).  Entries [2100155](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/2100155.html), [2100156](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/2100156.html), and [2100157](https://www.crystallography.net/cod/2100157.html) of the later for example point to the `.cif` about $\ce{Sr(OH)2 ·8H2O}$ of a study by [Ricci *et al.*](https://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?BS5014) at 20, 100 and 200 K, published 2005 in *Acta Cryst. B*.

---

*) A simplified definition of «organic compound» is that it is molecular and contains at least one carbon atom *excluding* carbon oxides ($\ce{CO, CO2}$, and others), their hydrates, and simple metal carbonates ($\ce{H2CO3, HCO^-_3, CO^{2-}_3}$).